# How can I dynamically add a select element to a form using Prototype & Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I have generated the code for a select & its objects using Rails:

```
var insert_tag = '<select class="select medium" id="category_id" name="search[category_id]"><option value="-1">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Boats and Cruisers</option>
<option value="2">Car Parts and Spares</option>
<option value="3">Caravans</option>
<option value="4">Coaches and Buses</option>
<option value="5">Commercial Parts</option>
<option value="6">Commercials</option>
<option value="7">Crash Repair Services</option></select>';
```

I have on JavaScript function which when called should insert this field into a blank div:

```
<div "form_field_a"></div>


$("form_field_a").insert(insert_tag);
```

But when this runs I just get this error:

```
content.toElement is not a function
[Break on this error] if (content && content.toElement) content = content.toElement();
```

I am new to JavaScript and have no idea why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Prototype, but your `div` element is missing an `id` attribute (currently it is invalid HTML):

```
<div id="form_field_a"></div>
```

Then it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/KqVdf/1

Also note that the value of `insert_tag` is one line without line breaks (got an error otherwise).

Comment: Great answer, jsfiddle.net - fantastic tool. When I generate the select code Rails puts a new line after each </option> tag, do you know how to remove this using JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: I simply appended the rails select_tag with .gsub(/\r\n?/, "") and it worked!