# Add new Dropdownlist on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have Dropdownlist like this[image]

But there must be shown single dropdownlist and to add other Dropdownlist click on other Time.
How this should be done??? Like This

This is ASP.NET code

```
       <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
         <td>                                                    
      <asp:DropDownList class="chzn-select validate[required]" ID="ddlconvenient1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
     <td>
   <div class="wrapper">                                                      
       <div class="checkboxes">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkDay1" CssClass="chzn-choices " runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
           </asp:CheckBoxList>                                                          
         </div>
     </div>
        </td>
       <td><button id="btnAdd" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>
     </tr>
          <tr id="tr1" style=" display:none;">
   <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlconvenient2" CssClass="chzn-select" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
              <td>
           <div class="wrapper">                                                      
        <div class="checkboxes">
          <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkDay2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
           </asp:CheckBoxList>
         </div></div>
      </td>
       </tr>
      <tr id="tr2" style=" display:none;">
             <td>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlconvenient3" CssClass="chzn-select" runat="server">
           </asp:DropDownList>
             </td>
         <td>
                                                 <div class="wrapper">

                                                            <div class="checkboxes">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkDay3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                    </div> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr id="tr3" style=" display:none;">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlconvenient4" CssClass="chzn-select" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                 <div class="wrapper">

                                                            <div class="checkboxes">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkDay4" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                    </div></div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

I make the 
Now I add button. How could I shown that by making Display yes one by one on button click
[image]

Comment: Any one of these demonstrate techniques that can be used to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340644/dynamically-add-input-type-select-with-options-in-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826235/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-select-element-to-a-form-using-prototype-rails
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/
http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript2/createSelectDynamically.htm

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

Using a server side aproach with c# you should do something like that:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="addDDL" runat="server" OnClick="addDDL_OnClick" />
```

CodeBehind

```
 protected List<string> NumberOfControls
    {
        get { return (List<string>)ViewState["NumControls"]; }
        set { ViewState["NumControls"] = value; }
    }
```

To add a new dropdown:

```
    protected void addDDL_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = this.NumberOfControls.Count();

        var dropdown = new DropDownList();
        dropdown.ID = "ddlApplyTo_" + count;
        dropdown.AutoPostBack = false;
        dropdown.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        dropdown.CssClass = "class";

        dropdown.DataSource = YourDataSource;
        dropdown.DataValueField = "Key";
        dropdown.DataTextField = "Value";
        dropdown.DataBind();

        this.NumberOfControls.Add("ddlApplyTo_" + count);
    }
```

To load the dropdowns properly:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack){
            // Initiate the list of dynamically added dropdowns
            this.NumberOfControls = new List<string>();
        }
        else{
            // Controls must be repeatedly created on postback
            this.createControls();
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void createControls()
    {
        var count = this.NumberOfControls.Count();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var dropdown = new DropDownList
                {
                    ID = "ddlApplyTo_" + i,
                    AutoPostBack = false,
                    ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static,
                    CssClass = "class"
                };
        }

        dropdown.DataSource = YourDataSource;
        dropdown.DataValueField = "Key";
        dropdown.DataTextField = "Value";
        dropdown.DataBind();
    }
```

To get the values from the dropdowns and put it on a string :

```
 var values = string.Empty;
 foreach (var s in this.NumberOfControls)
 {
    var ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl(s);
    values += ddl.SelectedItem.Text + ", ";
 }
```

To clear the dropdowns:

```
 this.NumberOfControls.Clear();
```

Comment: By Jquery funtion  var count = 1;
        function addRow(btn) {
            if (count < 4) {
//                alert(count);
                $("#tr" + count).show();
                count += 1;
            }
        }         I Display the <tr> tage which I mark as Display:None;

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {    
            for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {    
                if (!$('#tr' + i).is(':visible')) {
                    $('#tr' + i).css('display', 'block');
                    return;
                }
            }             
        })
    });        

</script>
```

But first change this :

```
<button id="btnAdd" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">Add</button>
```

to this:

```
<button id="btnAdd" type="button" >Add</button>
```

And add reference to jquery at the head of the page:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```